# Flutter error The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, future, dio

I got this error. When my `Future` method not return anything when in `else`. I don't know how to `return` `Future` data in else statement.

"The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type."

This is my method to connect with API.

```
  static Future<TestingResponse> getTestingDataResp(BuildContext context) async{
    Future<TestingResponse> testingResponse;
    //todo call real api
    var _api = await BaseNetworkRequest.noAuthRequest(context);
    String _path = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    response = await _api!.get(_path);
    var dataResp = TestingResponse.fromJson(response!.data);
    if(response!.statusMessage == 'success'){
      print(dataResp.data);
    }
    else{
      return testingResponse;
    }

  }
```

[image]
In this method, how to return Future type in else statement?

Comment: You need to return the `TestingResponse` type, not a future of it.

Comment: Yep.. I got it. I removed else statement and only return  ``` testingResponse``` type.